# Why can't I see my photos in finder?

Tags: finder, photos

When I search for photos in finder I can see just Photo Booth's photos:

[image]

But I have a lof of pictures in Photos app, why can't I see them?

**Update**

The option "use as system photo library" (in Italian: "usa come libreria foto di sistema") is disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to import a photo from Powerpoint, but it's the application that doesn't support it. Other applications such as Preview are able to use Photos as system library (the option is disabled because it is already selected).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might need to open the Photos app, and within Preferences choose "Use as System Photo Library"...

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/message/28138885#28138885

However if this doesn't work it would suggest something on your Mac isn't setup right and you should try backing up your data and reinstalling by following [these instructions](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18872?locale=en_GB).

Comment: The option is disabled (see the edit).

Comment: The latter would be my suggestion then. I don't know what the issue is sorry.

Comment: Answer found: I was trying to import a photo from Powerpoint, but it's the application that doesn't support it. Other applications such as Preview are able to use Photos as system library (the option is disabled because it is already selected).

Comment: I suggest you post an answer to your own question here.